# Efficient alternative to for loop with many if statements

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I have a list where the index represents the year, eg. y1, y2, y3, ..etc and the values represent the company that person worked for.

In the following example, p1[0]=c152 represents p1 in year 0 worked for company c152.

```
    0    1  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  
p1  c152 c3 c1  c8  c8  c8  c2  c1  c1  c1  c2  c2  c3  c3  c0  c8  c9  c9  c9  c8
p2  c170 c3 c8  c8  c8  c4  c1  c1  c2  c2  c2  c3  c3  c0  c0  c7  c5  c5  c8  c8
                ^               ^           ^       ^       ^                   ^
```

I am trying to identify a type of directed relationship - "followership" that is defined as if a person changed a job and the colleague has been there for at least a year and used to work together.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
p1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
p2  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

I have a python solution that is:

```
p1 = ['c152', 'c3', 'c1', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c2', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c8', 'c9', 'c9', 'c9', 'c8']
p2 = ['c170', 'c3', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c4', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c0', 'c7', 'c5', 'c5', 'c8', 'c8']
cowk = 0 
res = []
for i in range(len(p1)):
    if cowk == 0 and p1[i] != p2[i]: 
        res.append((0,0))
        continue 

    if cowk == 0 and p1[i] == p2[i]: 
        cowk = 1
        res.append((0,0))
        continue

    if cowk == 1 and p1[i] == p2[i]:
        if p1[i-1] == p1[i] and p2[i-1] == p2[i]:
            res.append((0,0))
            continue
        elif p1[i-1] == p1[i]: 
            res.append((1,0))
            continue
#             print(f'p1 {i}')
        elif p2[i-1] == p2[i]:
            res.append((0,1))
            continue
#             print(f'p2 {i}')
        else: 
            continue

    res.append((0,0))


5.79 µs ± 189 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In retrospective, I feel the real logic is after a coworking, if **there is a hole on the bottom left or top left in a 2x2 rolling window**, add 1 point to the diagonal of the hole.

Is there a more efficient way to store the data and efficiently calculate the output? (I feel there is a smarter way like matrix manipulation / vectorization / bit manipulation)

[image]

Comment: Are p1 & p2 a lot larger in your actual problem?  I tried a vectorized solution using Numpy, but it is slower for the posted sizes of p1 & p2.  This is normally because Numpy vectorization is swamped by the overhead of creating Numpy arrays for smaller arrays.

Comment: @DarrylG, they are not, if we keep employment at annual basis, they are at most ~40 elements (40 years), if at monthly level, maybe that can become ~500, I was wondering if even using list is the right choice. If there is a way to manipulate the bits to store and calculate, that will be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
p1 = ['c152', 'c3', 'c1', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c2', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c8', 'c9', 'c9', 'c9', 'c8']
p2 = ['c170', 'c3', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c4', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c0', 'c7', 'c5', 'c5', 'c8', 'c8']
new=[]
for i in range(0,len(p1)-1):
    if p2[i]==p2[i-1]==p1[i]!=p1[i-1]:
        new.append((0,1))
    elif p1[i]==p1[i-1]==p2[i]!=p2[i-1]:
        new.append((1,0))
    else:
        new.append((0,0))
print(f"{new}")
```

new:

```
p1 = ['c152', 'c3', 'c1', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c2', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c8', 'c9', 'c9', 'c9', 'c8']
p2 = ['c170', 'c3', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c4', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c0', 'c7', 'c5', 'c5', 'c8', 'c8']
new=[[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(len(p1))]
for i in range(0,len(p1)-1):
    new[i][1]=int(p2[i]==p1[i]==p2[i-1]!=p1[i-1])
    new[i][0]=int(p1[i]==p2[i]==p1[i-1]!=p2[i-1])
print(f"{new}")
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
```

Output shows that in a specific year if p1 was already there while p2 joined and vice versa.

Comment: The logic is slightly more complex, they need to coworked before at some point of time. My cowk flag and your logic implicitly assume p1 change job which both of them could be, hence all those "if" statements.

Comment: Are you saying that if p2 joins as new and p1 is already there for at least a year. Those years should be in the result also?

Comment: You need the years when either p1 or p2 joined new but other one is already there and they've already co-worked before.

   Am I right?

Comment: I'm editing the answer so that you have same output as your "res" and no matter who joins new (not necessarily p1) it'll show that year.

Comment: Thanks Nishant, this is a cleaner implementation but still doesn’t improve the performance that much.

Comment: My edited answer works like this: Its takes 2*2 block from both list (2 from each) and checks if it matches horizontally and vertically. If they intersect with the same value, the intersecting point is 1 and other 3 points of the block remains 0.

Comment: Now? I've added a more simpler. Is it faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
p1 = ['c152', 'c3', 'c1', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c2', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c8', 'c9', 'c9', 'c9', 'c8']
p2 = ['c170', 'c3', 'c8', 'c8', 'c8', 'c4', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c0', 'c0', 'c7', 'c5', 'c5', 'c8', 'c8']

res = [(0, 0)]
for i, company in enumerate(p1[1:], start=1):
    p1_res = 1 if company != p1[i-1] and company == p2[i] and p2[i] == p2[i-1] else 0
    p2_res = 1 if p2[i] != p2[i - 1] and company == p2[i] and company == p1[i - 1] else 0
    res.append((p1_res, p2_res))
print(res)
```